# Scheduling expensive calculation and using precalculated values between requests in Django

Tags: python, django

I have some function *expensiveFunction()* that takes several seconds to execute and returns a largish (5mb in JSON) array.

How can I schedule django to execute the function every x hours and then store the results somewhere so that when a user accesses a view, it returns those precalculated stored results?

Reading/writing to a textfile would have the overhead of reading in the file and then parsing JSON, and I feel like django sessions aren't suitable for this amount of data.

Using django 1.9.7 and python 3.4

Comment: There are multiple ways, so you may need to provide details to choose the best solutions: You can create a management command and crontab it, or you can make the JSON result a view of its own and cache it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a scheduled task in [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) which is a Distributed Task Queue and save the result from that expensiveFunction() in [Redis](http://www.redis.io) which is a key-value store and will reduce the overhead of reading from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should install an asynchronous app to work with django and create cron processes.

Nowadays the standard is [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/)
You could also research about Django Channels, that will be included in Django 1.10, but at this moment works as a Django separated app.